# Cannot add to cart after plugin to intercept

Tags: magento2, plugin

I am trying to intercept add to cart button.

What I intend to do: 
If customer is not logged in, throw error message. Else if customer is logged in, add item to cart.

I did it in following way. I got the error message `Cannot add to cart.` as expector for customer that is not logged in. But I can't get user to add the product if the customer is logged in. I  get the error message `We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.`.

What am I doing it wrong?
Note that I can add the particular product to cart if i commented out the logic in this plugin.

=============================================================================
Note updated code as advise. It seems like can't get customer session with following code. Everything works correctly if i commented out the customer session `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` and related code to check if customer is log in.

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Cart
{
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject,
        $productInfo,
        $requestInfo) {
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Cannot add to cart.'));
            return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
        }
       return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Should declare `protected $session` variable.

Comment: already declare in latest code still not working @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh updated

Comment: Change `$requestInfo = null` => `$requestInfo`.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have updated the code and make changes. it seems that everything work correctly if i commented out `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` and the logic to check session. The entire code works if i just put `return [$productInfo, $requestInfo]` only. It seems that it can't get customer session and stuck there.

Comment: Strange. What is your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh 2.1.11 I am pretty sure it working because i have another event observer that use the `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` and it can retrieve the session. But for this plugin it just hang at adding cart for the button and could not proceed.

Comment: Did you try to remove generation folder?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh yeah it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking customer logged in or not, use `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

Comment: Hi i upvoted your correction. That is  a mistake i make in my code. But it seems that it can't get customer session. with `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` in the plugin. It hangs at "adding" once i make the changes.

Comment: I have tried disabled all caching but still not working